# Pythons random.seed does not work when seeded with a hash

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am trying to seed an instance of pythons random. However when I run the code below it generates a different answer each time even if user input stays the same.

```
import random
import hashlib

mapSeed = hashlib.sha1(input("Enter seed: ").encode('utf-8'))
rnd = random.Random()
rnd.seed(mapSeed)
print(mapSeed)
print(rnd.random())
```

Comment: How are you setting `mapSeed`? Can you show some example output?

Comment: `mapseed` is a sha1 hash of a user inputted string

Comment: How _exactly_ are you setting `mapSeed`? Please create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mapSeed`, as the line `print(mapSeed)`, shows, is not a string, but an SHA1 HASH object. When you pass this to `random.seed`, it likely uses the (randomized) `hash()` of the object, hence the different results.

You need to extract the digest from the hash object before passing it to `random.seed`:

```
rnd.seed(mapSeed.digest())
```

(You can also just used the user input directly; there's no benefit to doing an SHA1 hash over it first)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the seed remains constant during all executions, it will never change. Look at this:

```
>>> import random
>>> r = random.Random()
>>> r.seed(515)
>>> r.random()
0.1646746342919
>>> r.random()
0.9567223584846931
>>> r.seed(515)
>>> r.random()
0.1646746342919
>>> r.random()
0.9567223584846931
```

However, since you develop your seed from a user inputted string, the value will not remain constant. Since the value that is returned by the `Random` object will not have a different value somewhere, you can't rely on it to be constant.

If you want the output to be constant, *the seed can not change.*

Answer (score -1):

One very important concept regarding "random numbers" is that are not actually  random, they are dependent of:
1) Algorithm used to generate the "random" sequence of numbers
2) The seed for the algorithm

The same seed will generate the same sequence of random numbers. Why? Because if you can have the same stream of random numbers you can actually test changes in your code using the very same stream of random numbers and check if the final output of your code is caused by changes in your code instead of occurrences of different random stream of numbers. This is very common in simulation processes (queues, traffic simulations, etc.).
So, same seed = same stream of random numbers.
Change the seed to have different streams of random number,

I hope it helps.